# Viao Laptop upgraded to Windows10

Tags: windows

I upgraded my Sony VIAO laptop model VPCSE2C5E from the factory-installed Windows 7 to Windows10 some 4 
Now I am lumbered with the screen brightness dimming to 10%. I tried all sorts of Display options, delayed hibernation, etc, to no avail.  The brightness buttons work up and down OK, but if I increase brightness then it quickly dims regardless within few seconds, sometimes few minutes.

1. Is there a  way I can solve this problem?
2. Do I need to upgrade Drivers, and if so, from where?
3. AS I cannot revert to Windows 7 with a complete Recovery to factory settings, meaning I have to backup every which is cumbersome and lengthy, does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You certainly could go back to Windows 7 if its been within 30 days.  Even if it has you can certainly just install Windows 7 over your current installation.  **Yes;**  You should download the current drivers for your drive from Sony's website.

Answer (score 0):

Open VAIO control center, Display, Automatic brightness, turn off automatic brightness control.
This worked for me.